# how to dom html url with php?

Tags: php, dom

This is the URL that I want to parse:
http://www.tsetmc.com/Loader.aspx?ParTree=151313&Flow=0

I use simple_html_dom.php but it can't read the HTML because the HTML is encoded.

So I think I should parse online and webpage source.
Is there any way that I can parse this web site?

The source code looks like this:

```
<html>
  <body>
   <table class="table1">
    <tbody>
        <tr><th>***title</th>
            <th class='ltr'>***99/2/24 12:10</th>
        </tr>
        <tr><td colspan="2">***message text here<hr /></td></tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>
```

my code:

```
<?php
 require_once('simple_html_dom.php');
 $url = "http://www.tsetmc.com/Loader.aspx?ParTree=151313&Flow=0";
 $html = file_get_html($url);
 foreach($html->find('th') as $element)
   echo $element->src . '<br>';
?>
```

Comment: What's the problem with `simple_html_dom.php`?

Comment: Please post the `php` code that you tried.

Comment: What's encoded here? How do you parse/scrape/get the data? Do you get errors? Does something not work?

Comment: i used that php code and nothing show in reuslt.

Comment: even i use file_get_content() but output is a encoded page.

Comment: What do you mean by "encoded"? Can you show us an example of the actual output you're getting? ([Edit] the question, don't try to paste into comments, because the formatting will get messed up.) Also check the tips on how to create a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue, as you pointed out was the encoding, it's `gzip` encoded. You can set the flag in curl `CURLOPT_ENCODING` to work around that. What it does, as provided by php-curl documentation:

> The contents of the "Accept-Encoding: " header. This enables decoding of the response. Supported encodings are "identity", "deflate", and "gzip". If an empty string, "", is set, a header containing all supported encoding types is sent.

Use the following php-curl code to get the response html like this:

```php
<?php

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "http://www.tsetmc.com/Loader.aspx?ParTree=151313&Flow=0",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "gzip",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);
echo $response;
?>
```

Then you can use the response html `$response` directly in `simple_html_dom.php` to parse the dom tree.

Here's a working version of the code.
http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/gb66-3kzq